# A library like BreezeJS that will work with Django and tastypie

Tags: javascript, django, odata, breeze, single-page-application

I'm looking to integrate Django models into a SPA and would like to use a library like [BreezeJS](http://www.breezejs.com/) or [JayData](http://jaydata.org/) to manage my offline/online data on the client side. Both of those require OData. OData does not have much support on Python except for [o-data py](http://code.google.com/p/odata-py/) which really only supports GAE.

So, my question is... Is there some Javascript framework/library that generally works as good as BreezeJS to manage off-line data but that works well with Django/Python?

Answer (score 2):

Jaydata works with REST endpoints, I try to put together a sample today for you with python.

Comment: I'm not a python guy so it took me some time to make it work but for CRUD it works for me. It required some tweaking to JayData, I can send it to you as a pre-release version and it will be in the next version out of the box. For more advanced use cases like paging, sorting, etc I'll do some more research.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to play with the example and clean it up.

Comment: Nice! Did you publish that?

Answer (score 1):

Breeze should supposedly work with anything that talks over HTTP. At least that's what, Ward Bell, one of the people behind Breeze says in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2ErSQj3SN8). You might  have to write your own adapter however.